# The script will only work from the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find a place to fix it. The script below is executed only from the second time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
  recalculate();
});
var wrapa = $("#infosp");
function recalculate(){
     var total = 0;   
function uncheckAll() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false)
        $('#amount').val('');
        wrapa.removeClass("fix-search");   
}
$(':button').on('click', uncheckAll)         
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        if (total == 0) {
            $('#amount').val('');
            wrapa.removeClass("fix-search");
        } 
    else {
            wrapa.addClass("fix-search");
            $('#amount').val(total);
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me find what the problem is.

UPDATE:

HTML example:

```
<input value="20" type="checkbox" class="my-activity">
<input value="40" type="checkbox" class="my-activity">

<div id="infosp" class="fix-search"> SP need for selected levels: <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" readonly=""> <input type="button" class="checka" value="Reload"> </div>
```

Comment: how are you calling `uncheckAll()` ? Please add the relevant HTML - a minimal working example - Thanks

Comment: Nothin is really is called on document ready all the functions are called upon click events or state change. It's not obvious what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I added an html code example.

Comment: The problem is that when I activate the "cheked" event for the first time, the result field #amount produces the result "NaN". 
But if I click on Reload and select checkboxes again, it counts the amount correctly.

Comment: I have already realized that the problem with the time between the user's browser and the data reading. But I have too little knowledge in JS structure, so I can't understand exactly where the error is.

Comment: It works fine for me. it is not producing `NaN` when i click on checked event first time. I can not reproduce this problem.

Comment: Please take a look at a live example - [link](https://foecity.ru/build/galatskaya-bashnya/) . 
The data table has checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you may have added the script in head or before infosop.
Just add the script at the bottom of body.

```
<body>
.
.
.
.
<script>
  YOUT CURRENT SCRIPT
</script>
</body>
```

If this doesn't work, just settimeout,

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
  recalculate();
});
var wrapa = $("#infosp");
function recalculate(){
     var total = 0;   
function uncheckAll() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false)
        $('#amount').val('');
        wrapa.removeClass("fix-search");   
}
$(':button').on('click', uncheckAll)         
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        if (total == 0) {
            $('#amount').val('');
            wrapa.removeClass("fix-search");
        } 
    else {
            wrapa.addClass("fix-search");
            $('#amount').val(total);
        }
    }
},2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for assuming, but it didn't work.
The script only works after user actions, so the delayed time does not help in solving the problem.

Comment: Can you submit the console output?

Comment: In the comments to the topic I gave a link to a live site with this problem.

Comment: oh the live site in he link worked without any problem on all my devices!!

Comment: It is very strange. I have the described error in chrome and in firefox on my computer...